# UIImageView with transition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, nstimer

So, I have this code:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(a) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

This code, repeat the action "a":

```
-(void)a {
    self.img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"wp%@.jpg", i]];
    if([i isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]){
    i = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
    }else if([i isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]]){
        i = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];
    }else     if([i isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]]){
        i = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    }
}
```

This void change the image "img", using the "i" value. I want when changing image, an effect is shown, like blurring and deblurring the "img".

Any idea how to do this effect?

Thanks for the attention,

Alberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it seems it would make sense to use an `NSInteger` or `int` for `i`. You could then write much more economically:

```
i += i<3 ? 1 : -2;
```

Don't forget to change your format string to `@"wp%i.jpg"`.

The animation would then be done like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 
                      delay:0 
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                    self.img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:
                        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"wp%i.jpg", i]];
                             }];
```

Comment: So, this code ("[UIView ...]" and "i += i<3 ? 1 : -2;") I put in the viewDidLoad from my UIViewController? If yes, it isn't working. Forgive me, I'm totally new at this. :-D Thanks!!